# Error uploading file from HTML form

Tags: php, html

Here is a problem.
I have an HTML form with several fields in it.
One of the fields - 'Upload file'.
When I upload a file, everything works properly. But when I choose to submit the form without a file, it gives me the error message: "There was an error uploading the file, please try again". Looks to me that the script thinks that uploading a file is mandatory.
How do I change it?

Here is my PHP:

```
//File upload

// Where the file is going to be placed 
$target_path = "uploads/";

// Add the original filename to our target path.  
//Result is "uploads/filename.extension" 
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}   

//End of file upload
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check using the function **is_uploaded_file**

try adding the following condition before calling the function move_uploaded_file

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'])) {
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! Now, though, there is another problem. I want the file to be deleted in the directory after it was sent as an attachment with an email. When there is a file uploaded, it all works fine. But if there isn't, I get this error message: Warning: unlink(uploads/) [function.unlink]: Is a directory in /mydomain.com/Hawaii/html/contact_email.php on line 191 How do I fix it?

Comment: the parameter of the function unlink must be a file .. in your case you passed 'uploads/' which is a folder.

Comment: How do I define the file?
I tried a few things, and they didn't work.
Also, when I use $target_path, the file actually gets deleted from the folder, whereas when I use a file variable, it doesn't.
I thought, maybe I should do a check similar to this:
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'])) {

Comment: Where did you exactly put the unlink function call ?

Comment: Right after the email is sent:
//Send the message
$numSent = $mailer->send($message);

printf("Sent %d messages\n", $numSent);

unlink($target_path);

Comment: Also, try using the function is_file before calling unlink.

Answer (score 0):

[`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) returns a bool, `true` or `false`, depending on the success of the operation.

A solution would be to check more rigorously, e.g. if a file was uploaded at all via [`is_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) function.

> For proper working, the function `is_uploaded_file()` needs an argument like `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']`, - the name of the uploaded file on the clients machine `$_FILES['userfile']['name']` does not work.

Comment: This worked, thank you!  
Now, though, there is another problem.
I want the file to be deleted in the directory after it was sent as an attachment with an email.
When there is a file uploaded, it all works fine.
But if there isn't, I get this error message:
Warning: unlink(uploads/) [function.unlink]: Is a directory in /mydomain.com/Hawaii/html/contact_email.php on line 191  

How do I fix it?

Comment: If these posts fixed this problem, accept one answer and ask another question with your successive issue. This is preferred over Q&A spirals through comments and edits.

Answer (score 0):

The target path of move_uploaded_files should be a folder, not a file.

You should also check if the folder is_writeable and is_dir.